# PHP site keeps opening to blank page, no errors

Tags: php

First, the premises: PHP loaded on IIS6 on Win2003 STD R2 SP2, PHP_5213 using FastCGI, MySQL_5145.

Customer sent me the site files, which I unzipped to `C:\InetPub\wwwroot\<site root>`, then I created a new site in IIS, pointed to `<site root>`, added `test.php` to the site files for testing and it works, but visiting `index.php` produces a blank page with no errors. The `readme.txt` file present makes reference to `application.php` and explains root folder var and sets it to a non-existent file.

I don't know PHP syntax, but I tried several logical changes with zero results. At this point I'm not even sure if that is the problem anymore.  With PHP, MySQL & site debugging have put in over 20 hours. Still confused, I have resorted to heavy drug use and purchased a small firearm, loaded with a single round (even this seemed to take an inordinate amount of time). I've given up all hope.

Someone please help save a new server and/or old administrator.

Comment: Refresh your cache. If that doesn't work, please post the index.php code.

Comment: It is possible that there is a error in the file. And because servers configuration it maybe hiding errors.
If you can post some code it would be easier to help.

Comment: Untagged as display-none; can be confused with CSS or jQuery-related tags

Answer (score 6):

Edit your `php.ini` file and set the `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` options to `On` so that you can have a chance to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 6):

Possible problems:

server configuration, which might be due to php is not being executed , how can you tell, look at the source of the file on the browser.

If you have an error in the php file, it might not wr0k, you can add two lines of code to report errors.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);  
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);  
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

check your logs.

If you are not familiar with php configuration with FastCGI or IIS you can use lamp bundles for windows.

Answer (score 2):

When moving files from one server to another and getting the blank page, check whether the code is using short opening php tags like `<?` instead of the full `<?php` opening tag.  If it is and the original server has the following line in the php.ini file...

```
short_open_tag = On
```

but the new server has...

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

then the blank screen may be the result.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with a few servers I didn't have full access to and some didn't have errors enabled by default.  I had to call echo error_get_last() at bottom of each page.