# How to get color value with asp

Tags: html, input, asp-classic, colors

There is a demo file on http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_color and in the source codes, there is a "demo_form.asp" file.

Can anyone tell me what is the source code of this asp file? And if it is possible also php version of this asp file.

Comment: looks like nothing important in this asp file. you could even submit empty form, or form with any value. yes, most from ASP could be converted to PHP.

Comment: @Lankymart I just want to learn how to get the value of a color with html5's "color" input type..

Comment: @WhoCares Just like any other form request, same way you would get a any input type. In asp it's `Request("name of the input")` (to check `GET` and `POST`) if you're using `GET` use `Request.QueryString("name of your input")` or `POST` use `Request.Form("name of your input")`.

Answer (score 1):

If I was to guess I'd say it is something like this;

```html
<html>
<body>
<h3>Input was received as:</h3>
<h3>
favcolor=<%= Request.QueryString("favcolor") %>
</h3>

<p>This page was returned to you from the server. The server has processed your input and returned this answer.</p>
<p>It is not a part of the HTML5 tutorial to teach you how the server is processing this input. If you want to learn more about processing form input, please read our 
PHP or ASP tutorial.</p>   
<p>Use the back button in the browser to return to the example.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) you could use for [php](/questions/tagged/php);

```php
favcolor=<?php $_GET['favcolor'] ?>
```

Comment: I'm no php expert but as far as I know that is the equivalent syntax.

Comment: @WhoCares Is your `input type="color"` named "favcolor" in your calling page? I've based my answer off the w3schools page you linked.

Comment: @WhoCares Do you have [tag:php] configured on your web server?

Comment: I am using the exact same html file to call this php file. And yes, I have apache installed on localhost so I have to have a .php file of this asp file. Actually asp part is enough but I thought same wtih you but it didn't work.

Comment: @WhoCares Have you managed to output some simple php to test your apache server is configured correctly? Try something simple like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, does that work? This might also help - [PHP site keeps opening to blank page, no errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2473926/692942)

Comment: my apache server is working correctly (not localhost) I have my webpage for 6 years and works perfect. btw, the code u gave works like that: "favcolor=".. I mean nothing is coming as an answer, but NULL.

Comment: @WhoCares If you just open that page you will get null because your form has to submit to it first for `$_GET` to be populated. I assumed you built the form page from the example (as it's all there, just standard `HTML`). If you want to test it like that try something like `yourpage.php?favcolor=%23ff8040` that should return `favcolor=%23ff8040` in your page.

Comment: I want it like this way: http://htmldersleri.org/yedek/ornekler/dene.php?dosyaadi=tryhtml5_input_type_color I just want it to work properly.